# How do you use fstab to set mountpoint containing spaces

Tags: mount, automount

I have tried every combination I could think of to no avail. None of these work:

```
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 /Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 /Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 "/Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music" apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 '/Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music' apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 /Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes\040Media/Music apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 /Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music apfs rw
UUID=2960F79CE8E2 "/Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music" apfs rw
```

Comment: What version of macos are you using?

Comment: MacOS version 10.14.4

Answer (score 0):

Try with symlinks.

ln -s "/Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music" /Users/davec/Music/iTunesMedia

sudo mount UUID=2960F79CE8E2 /Users/davec/Music/iTunesMedia